# cron: how to add a fixed time offset (delay) to ssh Command

Tags: time, ssh, delay

I did some Google searches but could not find this, is there a way to delay ANY command into SSH?
As an example, I want to start a Crontab tomorrow  but I want to set it up right now

```
    crontab mycron.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one dinky way to do it is to put a sleep  && in front of it like this:

```
sleep 600 && echo "10 minutes later!"
```

Comment: That works! It does hold my cursor for the specified time, is there any way to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

There is [`at`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at) command in Linux, which does exactly what you need. Something like this should do the job:

```
echo "your command" | at 11:00
```

Comment: You probably need to install `at` on the remote system.